# Empty Migrations are generated in code first ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have been trying to generate migration but some reason, generated migrations is empty except the basic definition of function up and down but empty inside.

Model class

```
public class StoryDB
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StoryContent { get; set; }
    private int heartsCount { get; set; }
    private int commentsCount { get; set; }
    private int shareCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
}
```

Database Context class

public class StoreDB : DbContext
    {
       public StoreDB() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

```
    }
    public virtual DbSet <StoryDB> Stories { get; set; }

}
```

Note that I am using the same connection DefaultConnection which is used to by Identity Classes
When I generate the initial seeding class that generates perfectly (i.e. all user tables like roles and users)
However when i try to generate the first migration after seed class, then nothing appears in the class

Comment: Check the migrations folder on your Solution Explorer. You get an empty migration if there are no changes to be made. That is, if your seed migration already holds all the changes you have made. Have you updated the DB after the seed migration?

Comment: No mate that is not true, I have updated the DB, one question I have been following this [Code First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj591621.aspx) , now in this example he **added** entry as well. Now I am fairly certain that you don't need to add an entry for creating migrations, right?

Comment: No, you don't need to make an entry to the DB, but you do need to call UpdateDatabase so the migration is taken to the DB. Have you done that since your seed migration?

Comment: Yes as matter of fact I did.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the DbContext which entities you want to map to the DB. In your case StoryDB:

```
    public class StoreDB : DbContext
    {
       public StoreDB() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
        public virtual DbSet<StoryDB> Stories { get; set; }

    }
```

Note that DbSet has a generic parameter, which tells EF the actual type to use.

Comment: Sorry due to formatting error , it was not shown, but I specified the class to map to

Comment: Then my answer is irrelevant. Is this your first migration? maybe EF doesn't see changes? Delete the db, delete previous migrations and try adding it again.

Comment: Is this your first migration? No actually I have done seeding migration. maybe EF doesn't see changes? I guess so, Delete the db? Hmm not tried will do and respond

Comment: Delete the db, delete previous migrations- Done that still doesn't fix it

Comment: That's quite strange. If you delete the previous migrations and create them again, at least is should create a migration which included what the previous migrations did. I think you should update your question with your migrations configuration and the migrations you have at the moment. A migration will add the changes in the model that EF sees, but it's impossible to tell why EF doesn't see your changes without knowing your current model, migrations and DB.

Comment: in my case at first it had generated, but after deleting db and migs, it is generating empty now